# Multiple columns in a summary field to calculate distinct count

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5, crystal-reports-server

I have in my sql return statement as

```
Date            Id

02/12/2012      100
02/12/2012      100
02/13/2012      101
02/13/2012      100
```

When i show the total visits in crystal report, i show it as

```
2
```

but actual result is

3

ie. based in date and Id.

In crystal report i have a summary field calculating the total based on

```
"Distinct count of date".
```

`I want to use "Distinct count of date, Id", w`ill that be possible in crystal reports?

so that i can get 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a formula that combines both data values and do a distinctCount() on that. For example, something like `totext({table.date}, 'MM/dd/yyyy') + ' | ' + totext({table.ID})`

Comment: Thanks, i get "Too many arguments given for 'MM/dd/yyyy', any thoughts?

Comment: Am not able to use distinctcount, any other way?

Comment: "A field is required here" is what i get when i try distinctcount()

Comment: @Sharpeye500 Put your formula in your report and make sure it is returning what you want. It should give you strings like '02/12/2012 | 100' when it's working properly (be sure to account for your datatypes, etc.). Once it does, right-click the field in the report, hit 'Insert', and then 'Summary'. Select 'Distinct count' and pick a section you want it to display.